# Mezzanine search_form

Tags: python, django, search, mezzanine, search-form

This what the error when I click the "Search" in html.

```
{% search_form 'all' %}
```

Can some one help me this? Thank you

```
**ValueError at /search/**

**need more than 1 value to unpack**
```

Traceback

```
/.virtualenvs/yap/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mezzanine/core/views.py in search

**117. search_model = get_model(*request.GET.get("type", "").split(".", 1))** 

/.virtualenvs/yap/lib/python2.7/site-packages/mezzanine/utils/models.py in get_model

**35. app_label, model_name = app_label.split('.')**
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd same problem. Solved by upgrading mezzanine version.